Azure Bicep support to target single module to deploy? || Is there an az/bicep equivalent to terraform apply -target=module.my_app.module.something
module app '../../../projects/my/application/app.bicep' = {
name: 'app'
}

module test '../../../projects/my/application/test.bicep' = {
name: 'test'
}

module sample '../../../projects/my/application/sample.bicep' = {
name: 'sample'
params {
p1: 'p1'
}
}

Can I provision just the sample module somehow?
az deployment group create --resource-group ${{variables.rg}} --template-file ${{variables.Templatefile}
using above command with azure devops pipeline unable deploy particular module.

your ${{variables.Templatefile}} need to resolve to ../../../projects/my/application/sample.bicep

Probably create a new variable

How to do it pls share sample

you could always hardcode the sample.bicep path

its not working

Have you tried conditional module provisioning ? @itlumeesatishB refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/conditional-resource-deployment

yes . but its not worked as expected.

it works for me i was able to create a targeted resouce amoung the list of avaiable modules please check with the solution provided @itlumeesatishB

have you got the chance to review the solution provided? Is there anything I can do on my end to assist further? @itlumeesatishB


Azure Bicep support to target single module to deploy

You can use Conditional deployments in Bicep with the if expression which helps you provision the required resource among the available list of module resources in your bicep configuration file.
It work similar to terraform target  resource provisioning
I tried a terraform configuration as per the requirement in the below configuration.
main.bicep:
module app 'app.bicep' = if (deployModule == 'app') {
  name: 'app'
}


module test 'test.bicep' = if (deployModule == 'test') {
  name: 'test'
}


module sample 'sample.bicep' = if (deployModule == 'sample') {
  name: 'sample'
  params: {
    p1: 'p1'
  }
}

sample.bicep:
param p1 string

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-09-01' = {
  name: 'sampleage${uniqueString(deployment().name)}'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
}

Continue with rest of the modules for app.bicep & test.bicep
Since our requirement is to provision the targeted resource using bicep we can achieve this by using conditional formating.
Deployment:
az deployment group create --resource-group vinay-rg --template-file main.bicep --parameters deployModule='sample'



Refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/conditional-resource-deployment
I would like to run terraform only for a specific resource - Stack Overflow by Julio Daniel Reyes
Target resources | Terraform | HashiCorp Developer
